# gasCost of opcode "STATICCALL" in Geth VM Trace

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, opcode, transaction-trace, static-call

```
  {
    "pc": 4765,
    "op": "STATICCALL",
    "gas": 222711,
    "gasCost": 219243,
    "depth": 1,
    ...
  }
```

As above, Geth VM Trace (https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x457c267f3acea528fdf0159a05d0794270a858fed9ad71b96d6ad66b44975eec) shows that gas cost of "STATICCALL" is 219243, which seems impossible because it's even larger than the entire gas consumption of the transaction.

So, how to interpret this?

Answer (score 1):

Gas , refers to the amount of gas remaining after the execution of the STATICCALL function while gasCost is the cost of static call. The former is available for other calls in the transaction and refunded if not used .

The cost of STATICCALL is 700 gas.

To verify, at step 323 , you have a STATICCALL

Gas:    222711
GasCost:    219243

But at the next step 324, the Gas available to that transaction is  218543.

219243 - 218543 = 700.

The documentation of this is sparse. The only reference I could find was in EIP 1380.

> If block.number >= FORK_BLKNUM, then decrease the cost of CALL,
> DELEGATECALL, CALLCODE and STATICCALL from 700 to 40, if and only if,
> the destination address of the call equals to the address of the
> caller

#### References:

- EIP-1380: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1380

Comment: Thanks. But how much gas does STATICCALL cost in this case(0x457c267f3acea528fdf0159a05d0794270a858fed9ad71b96d6ad66b44975eec)? Apparently not 219243, right?

Comment: Can you share you contract? What is happening is that STATICCALL is reading state from another contract, hence jumping out of the first and giving all the gas to the next contract; so its not use more like its work is done in that contract and allocatiing gas from the rest of the instructions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, can I calculate the gas cost of "STATICCALL" by subtracting "Gas" of the next opcode(say "PUSH1") from "Gas" of "STATICCALL". The difference between them should be the actual gasCost of "STATICCALL", right?

Comment: Updating my answer